# MAUI App Cannot Be Uploaded to Apple App Store Because of App Icon Issue

Tags: maui

I'm trying to upload my MAUI app to the Apple App Store so I can open it up for beta testing.  I'm trying to follow along with the documentation...so far I've created an archive of the app, it shows up in Xcode on my Mac, and I'm trying to upload the archive now.

I get all the way through the process on Xcode, and it fails at the end with the error message "Invalid App Store icon.  The App Store icon in the asset catalog ... can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel."  Since MAUI is the tool that creates all the icons I don't really know what control I have (if any) to tweak this at all. Any known issues and/or workarounds here?

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this was my fault I think.  Turns out my logo did have the transparent bit set, even though there was nothing transparent on the logo (i.e. it had solid colors over the entire thing).  I took off the transparent bit, recompiled, and tried uploading again and it failed again, but with a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a long frustrating experience trying to resolve this issue. The relevant part of the MAUI documentation is [Recolor the Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#recolor-the-background), particularly the red caution notice.

[image]

This means a background image is required otherwise the App Store Connect verification will fail.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" 
        ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

With my app icon as the `appiconfg.svg` I used the default `appicon.svg` file that is generated when creating a new MAUI app and edited it in a text editor to set the color to white. Once I added the background I was able to upload successfully.

Comment: I just wasted an afternoon on editing SVG files... installing 5 different editors to see if any could remove aplha channel sigh Visual Studio should check for this when building for deployment