Invalid icon file
I have a .NET MAUI app that I am trying to publish to Apple's TestFlight. When I submit it through transporter it fail with the error:
Asset validation failed (90717)
Invalid large app icon. The large app icon in the asset catalog in “THEAPP.Maui.app” can’t be transparent or contain an alpha channel. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/app-icons. (ID: e7cea40a-7a27-4518-930b-2f2095a753b1)
I have checked the files in the AppIcon folder of the resources and there are 2 files, one that is 58x58 pixels and one that is 1024x1024 pixels. Both do not have a transparent background or an alpha channel on them. I have done everything I can think of to resolve this. All of the suggestions are from several years ago and I've tried all of their suggestions/solutions but with no success.

Try this site https://mediamodifier.com/svg-editor# , upload your image and save it as SVG, remove those 2 files from your project

See this answer before doing the above step https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597662/3392605

Do you have the ForegroundFile of your image? Can your project load the icon normally on the iPhone simulator?

I have the ForegroundFile now and the icon gets loaded onto my actual iPhone but the store still says it is invalid.

Is your icon image .svg format? Will an error still occur if you change the icon?

Does it help Can't publish iOS due to: The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'myapp.app' can't be transparent nor contain an Alpha Channel.?

In the Can't publish iOS, op's solution is to add notes to the document, have you tried this solution?
